# How to use Flask partial templates that require scripts without duplication?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

Let's say I have a partial template post.html:

```html
<h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
<p>{{ post.content }}</p>

<script src='myscript.js'></script>
```

And a regular template posts.html:

```html
<h1>Posts</h1>
{% for post in posts %}
    {% include "partials/post.html" %}
{% endfor %}
```

Should I reference the script from every template I want to use the partial from instead of from the partial itself?
Or is there a better way to prevent the script tag from being duplicated?

Comment: If I refer to this post I assume I should  put the script inside the regular template?

Comment: Typically, if you use template inheritance (and have a `base.html` or `layout.html` as most tutorials on tempates mention) then script includes should go in here, ensuring they appear on every template.

Answer (score 0):

Script tags should go in regular templates that use the partial templates